# Screen flickers even when Application.ScreenUpdating is False

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

Hi i am new to VBA so i apologies in advance if my code looks bad. My problem is, I would like to stop my screen from flickering when i run my macro using a button. However, I have tried multiple codes to solve this but to no avail. I have tried `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the start of my sub and switched back to True before ending the sub but the screen still flickers. Is there any other solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
Sub UpdateData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Debug.Print Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim EMS As Worksheet
Dim TD As Worksheet
Dim JV1 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

Workbooks.Open ("HR Headcount Report 2018 Australia SEPTEMBER.XLSX")
Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
Set EMS = Sheets("Employee Movement Summary")
EMS.Activate
Range("J19").Copy
wb1.Activate
Range("J34").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

wb2.Activate
Set TD = Sheets("Turnover Dashboard")
TD.Activate
Range("J44").Copy
wb1.Activate
Range("J2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
wb2.Activate
Range("J47").Copy
wb1.Activate
Range("J3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

P.S. This is the first half of my code. I suspect that the multiple use of `.Activate` is causing the problem. If that is the case, how can I rewrite my code to avoid using `.Activate`?

Comment: You can treat `.Activate` in the same way as `.Select` - here is the ["How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) guide - things like `EMS.Range("J19").Copy` or `wb1.ActiveSheet.Range("J34").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: I additionally recommend to avoid `ActiveWorkbook` too by setting the opened workbook to the variable directly: `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("HR Headcount Report 2018 Australia SEPTEMBER.XLSX")`. • Also you should specify the workbook for **every** sheet `Set EMS = wb2.Worksheets("Employee Movement Summary")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will guide you somewhat to remove all your Activate statements:

```
Sub UpdateData()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Debug.Print Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim EMS As Worksheet
Dim TD As Worksheet
Dim JV1 As Worksheet

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = ActiveSheet
'better to refer to the actual sheet name rather than the Active Sheet, amend as required

Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("HR Headcount Report 2018 Australia SEPTEMBER.XLSX")

Set EMS = wb2.Sheets("Employee Movement Summary")
EMS.Range("J19").Copy
ws1.Range("J34").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Set TD = wb2.Sheets("Turnover Dashboard")
TD.Range("J44").Copy
ws1.Range("J2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
TD.Range("J47").Copy
ws1.Range("J3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have managed to remove all `.Activate` from my sub. However, my screen still flickers when I run my macro with a button as it switches between workbooks. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @LimHongEn you could make the workbook invisible until you finish copying data over then make it visible again, something like `wb2.Visible = False`